# Rather than Response.Write, how can I write binary data to a file and then display it using an HTML 'object'?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm not sure if my search terms are off but I've been looking for a way to convert binary data back to a file and then display that file using an HTML `object` tag.

Basically, I want to display a PDF or some other type of file using an HTML `object`. This has to be dynamically generated from binary or data type `byte` instead of sourced from a location. 
Normally, we can set the `data` attribute to a static file location to display a PDF or other file type within the DOM but I'm trying to figure a way to somehow read a generated file on the fly, converted from binary.

**What I have right now uses `Response.Write` to write a file to the HTTP response header and download a file. I'm not sure where to start if I want the file to be in an HTML `object`**

```
        SqlConnection sqlDnldExpDocConn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ExpenseReportsConnectionString"].ToString());
        SqlCommand sqlDnldExpDocCmd = new SqlCommand();
        sqlDnldExpDocCmd.Connection = sqlDnldExpDocConn;
        sqlDnldExpDocCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlDnldExpDocCmd.CommandText = "SELECT [docName], [docType], [docData] FROM [ExpDocuments] WHERE [expID] = @expID";
        sqlDnldExpDocCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@expID", Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["expid"]));

        sqlDnldExpDocConn.Open();
        SqlDataReader sqlDnldExpDocDataReader = sqlDnldExpDocCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

        // If rows exists then there is data to display
        if (sqlDnldExpDocDataReader.HasRows)
        {
            while (sqlDnldExpDocDataReader.Read())
            {
                // Read data and generate objects
                string docName = sqlDnldExpDocDataReader["docName"].ToString();
                string docType = sqlDnldExpDocDataReader["docType"].ToString();
                Byte[] docData = (Byte[])sqlDnldExpDocDataReader["docData"];

                // Prepair, Convert and download file
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.ClearHeaders();

                // Replace any spaces in the original file name to enable the response header to read the name
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + docName.Replace(" ", "_"));

                //Set the content type as file type
                Response.ContentType = docType;

                //Write the file content
                this.Response.BinaryWrite(docData);
                this.Response.End();

            }
        }
        // If no rows exists, no data was found. Handle accordingly.
        else
        {
        }
        sqlDnldExpDocDataReader.Close();
        sqlDnldExpDocConn.Close();
        sqlDnldExpDocConn.Dispose();
```

I've thought about moving the file to a temp. location on the server and then displaying it but I'm shooting for something a little more robust.
Any ideas?

Comment: "...instead of sourced from a location..." You mean a file location? You are trying to load a byte array in memory in an `object`?

Comment: I've voted to close, as there's plenty of examples on how to do this. But in general, you generate the PDF in a .ashx generic handler and then you set the `object` element's `src` attribute to point to the handler.

Comment: @Zack Right, a file location. Within an HTML Object though. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp

Comment: @mason Of course, I'm not sure why I didn't think of using a handler. I've seen plenty of questions involving downloading the file but I suppose my search terms weren't completely thought out for this particular scenario.  I appreciate it.